# When creating an Azure storage resource, is the default/selected region random or it's a calculated recommendation?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager

When creating an Azure storage resource, there is a default, selected region in the location drop down.

Is this "randomly" selected or its a "calculated recommendation"

I'm asking because I keep getting the same selected region even with a second resource.

Also, my geographic location is nowhere near that selected region. The region I would expect is South Africa North or South Africa West

[image]

Comment: Looking forward to your correct answer, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more calculated than random - trying to match capacity with geo... it's really more of a "if you don't care use this region" than anything else.

Comment: Thanks. So just to be clear, absolutely no relation to my detected location?

Comment: No, that's the geo part - put another way it is "trying to find somewhere close to you that has the most available capacity".  If you're in SA - there aren't alot of other datacenters near there yet - UAE is actually the closest afaiki.  For people that don't care about location, that algo works.  If you do care, pick what you need.

Comment: Thank-you, very helpful. Sorry to nag you with another question. When you say "most available capacity", do you mean more capabilities in Azure services (IaaS, PaaS, SaaS) than my detected geo has to offer?

Or the selected geo is less "crowded"?

Comment: just "less crowded"